# System symbols in sqlite statement

Tags: sqlite

I have such statement

```
SELECT _id, _data, title, album, artist, album_id, artist_id, duration, track, _size FROM audio WHERE ( alive=? ) AND (_data LIKE '/storage/sdcard0/Musicc/website'/') ORDER BY title
```

And i get exception.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "') ORDER BY title" (code 1):
```

It seems to my the problem is that i have symbol "'" in folder name "website'". 
how can i ignore this symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'/storage/sdcard0/Musicc/website'/'` string in your statement has the `'` character inside, which is forbidden (how can SQLite know if you meant to put `'` in the string, or you meant to end string at that position?). If you want to include `'` in the string, escape it by typing `''`, so your statement would be:

```
SELECT _id, _data, title, album, artist, album_id, artist_id, duration, track, _size FROM audio WHERE ( alive=? ) AND (_data LIKE '/storage/sdcard0/Musicc/website''/') ORDER BY title
```